# Spring Boot AOP @before not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have written this code : 
It seems perfect but not working 
When i run the code it runs fine 
I hit the URL for (/) and only the greetings method is called

### AOP method is not getting called

This is my main Class

```
DemoApplication.java

package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.aop.AOPSample;
com.services.TaskService;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.aop","com.services"})
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}



@RequestMapping("/")
public void greetings(){
    new TaskService().startService();
    System.out.println("In Greetings");
}
}

AOPSample.java
package com.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class AOPSample {
@Before("execution(public void com.services.TaskService.startService())")
public void beforeSampleCreation() {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}

}

TaskService.java

package com.services;

public class TaskService {
public void startService(){

}
public void endService(){

}
}
```

Output:
   In Greetings

Comment: Spring AOP is proxy based and will only work on spring managed beans. You are creating an instance yourself instead of using a spring managed instance.

Comment: so how should i recode

Comment: I need more explaination for making this work \

Comment: As stated `TaskService` has to be a spring bean, currently it isn't. This same question has been answered numerous times before so you might want to do a little search on stack overflow...